# What is the difference between biclustering and clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, clustering, statistics

After reading the wiki page for biclustering (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclustering), I am really confused on what is the difference between biclustering and clustering?

Any explanation/comparisons would be really appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Clustering find groups of observations in a p dimensional space (p features).

[image: 3D space]

Biclustering enables you to find clusters in a subset of features. 
Then why would you need other features than this subset to perform the clustering?
Because locally you may find dimensions a & b useful to identify a cluster (green cluster in the figure) and somewhere else in the space, dimensions b & c might be useful to identify other clusters (light blue and purple clusters on the figure).

[image: 2D projections of the 3D space]

Sources :

- https://towardsdatascience.com/subspace-clustering-7b884e8fff73
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclustering